# ErrorDocument 403 /closed.php

Tags: .htaccess

> ErrorDocument 403 /closed.php

На домашнем сервере путь принимает нормально, а после залития это воспринимается как текст, и на экран в итоге выводит текст "`/closed.php`", путь принимает только абсолютный с `http://`

Как настроить путь?

**Добавлено**

Проблемы:

1. Нужно перенаправить именно на файл с сервера, к примеру который лежит рядом с `.htaccess`
2. Структура работы следующая: человек сидит на своем компе; как только что-то написал, делает `commit` на одну из веток (`master / develop`), автоматом все это дело заливается в нужное место при `push`. Соответственно адреса разные. Доступ прекрасно настраивается, если писать `http://develop/close.php`, но при коммите на мастер он не будет работать, т.к. адрес другой.

На счет 2-го пункта я конечно могу настроить, чтобы он сервере при заливании менял путь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Этож](http://www.htaccess.net.ru/doc/ErrorDocument/ErrorDocument2.php) так сложно

```
# содержание файла .htaccess:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 http://htaccess.net.ru/error/404.shtml

ErrorDocument 403 http://htaccess.net.ru/error/403.shtml

ErrorDocument 401 http://htaccess.net.ru/error/401.shtml

ErrorDocument 500 http://htaccess.net.ru/error/500.shtml
```

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Полный путь работает, а относительно текущего положения .htaccess не получается.

Comment: проблема была решена путем шаманства в коде на сервере